# How do I move the three.js animated object to the right with GSAP without covering HTML text?

Tags: html, css, three.js, gsap

I am new to web design so forgive me if this is a basic problem. I have an animated object in three.js which I would like to move to the left side of the screen using GSAP. I also have a text "Hello" on the left side of the screen. When the GSAP animation moves the animated object, it is moving the entire scene (it covers the HTML text briefly when it moves). If there a way to just move the object and not the entire scene or keep the HTML text visible at all times?

Here is the three.js code.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import {RGBELoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js';

// Scene 1 - Landing Page 

container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );

document.body.appendChild( container );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    700
);

const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

camera.position.x = 90
camera.position.y = 200
camera.position.z = 250
orbit.update();

//const grid = new THREE.GridHelper(30, 30);

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

const rgbeLoader = new RGBELoader();

renderer.linearEncoding = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 4;

let car;

rgbeLoader.load('./assets/MR_INT-005_WhiteNeons_NAD.hdr', function(texture) {
    texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
    scene.environment = texture;

    gltfLoader.load('./assets/scene.gltf', function(gltf) {
        const model = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(model);
        car = model;
    });
});

function animate(time) {
    if(car)
        car.rotation.y = - time / 3000;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});
```

also the HTML I have created along with CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
    <script src="./js/scripts.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js" type="module"></script>
    <!--
        npm install @parcel/config-default -d
        
        "staticFiles": {
    "staticOutPath": "static"
    }
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapi.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
html {
    background: black;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }

.canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

.title{
    color: whitesmoke
}

.title h1{
    color:whitesmoke
}
```

Finally the basic GSAP script.

```
// GSAP Animations 
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.to("#canvas",{
    x: 350,
    duration: 2,
    delay: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<div class="canvas-container">
      <canvas class="webglHH"> </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webglHH {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.canvas-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.title h1 {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 52px;
}
```

---

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x800080);

const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webglHH");

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = -1;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
renderer.render(scene, camera);
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
scene.add(ambientLight);
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
scene.add(directionalLight);
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
let mesh;

loader.load("REACT.glb", (gltf) => {
  mesh = gltf.scene;
  mesh.scale.x = 10;
  mesh.scale.y = 10;
  scene.add(mesh);
});

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enabled = true;

gsap.to(".canvas-container", {
  x: 350,
  duration: 3,
  delay: 1,
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true,
});

function resize() {
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  resize();
});

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```